# Declare Color as constant

Tags: c#, .net

How can I declare the `Color` type as `const` like this:

```
private const Color MyLovedColor = Color.Blue;
```

That doesn't work because the Color.Blue is static not const.

(readonly won't help me because I need the color for an attribute which "support" constants only

Comment: How about changing your attribute to take (A),R,G,B params?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "support constants only"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the `KnownColor` enumeration. It will likely cater for what you need.

Comment: I used it And then received the Color with Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor color)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromknowncolor.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can assign a const only a value that is a literal. In your case I would then prefer a string literal and define your color as following:

```
const string mycolor = "Blue";
```

Then, wherever you need your color, you perform the backward conversion:

```
Color mynewcolor = Color.FromName(mycolor);
```

I am sorry, but this is the only way to keep it `const`.

**EDIT**: Alternatively you can also keep your color as (A)RGB attributes, stored into a single `int` value. Note, that you can use a hexadecimal literal then to explicitly set the different components of your color (in ARGB sequence):

```
const int mycolor = 0x00FFFFFF;
Color mynewcolor = Color.FromArgb(mycolor);
```

Comment: That only works if you want your A is 00. A > 0 alpha will not compile. You'd need to convert it convert it to a decimal int, having a negative value.

Answer (score 4):

`System.Drawing.Color` is a `struct`, which means you cannot have a constant value of it.

Comment: They know this, they want to know how to get around it.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Isn't "you *cannot* get around this" a legitimate answer?

Comment: "you cannot get around this" is rare in coding, there is often a work-around, especially if the limitation is well-known.

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin: Obviously. My point is that there is no head-on solution. If the constraints can be relaxed or redefined (e.g. you can modify the code for the attribute) the problem can be solved.

Comment: I Forgot the comment on this answer, look on my comment under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static readonly Color MyLovedColor = Color.Blue;
```

I thanks that's the closest you can get?

Comment: (readonly won't help me because I need the color for an attribute which "support" constants only

Comment: yep - but a const is not an option so there is no 'solution' as such. Point taken though.

Comment: @ChrisF, now that you have that little Diamond near your name, you can delete this answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you used the long value returned by the RGB function as your constant?

for example the value returned for a light blue `RGB(51,255,255)`  is `16777011`

so

```
Private Const ltBlue As Long = 16777011    
txtbox1.backcolor = ltBlue
```